# Image inside canvas: distinguish onclick inside image and outside image (but inside canvas)

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, onclick

EDITED QUESTION AND CODE: if I now use the return statement in function move_background() and save the image inside the var imageObj as suggested, my code is still not working and plays sound2 both when inside and outside image (sound 3 is correctly played when outside canvas though), any ideas why?

```
</script>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid white;" onclick="myFunct()"></canvas>

<!-- audio source is specified later-->
<audio id="audio"></audio>

<style>
    #myCanvas { position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin:auto; }
</style>

<script>

    var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");     
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = make_background();

    function make_background()
    {

      img =  new Image();;
      img.src="img.gif";
      img.id = "myImage";
      img.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(img, (canvas.width-img.width)/2, (canvas.height-img.height)/2);
      }
      return img
    }

      function play(){
         var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
         audio.play();
      }

        function myFunct() {
          var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
          // PLAY DIFFERENT SOUND IF ANSWER IS RIGHT OR WRONG
          document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
             if(e.target == imageObj){ // inside canvas and inside image
               audio.src = "sound1.mp3";
               audio.play();
             }
             else if (e.target === canvas && e.target !== imageObj) { // inside canvas but outside image
                audio.src = "sound2.mp3";
                audio.play();
             }
             else{
               audio.src = "sound3.mp3";
               audio.play();
             }
          // GENERATE RANDOM LOCATION
          var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
          var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
          var obj = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
          obj.style.top = x + "px";
          obj.style.left = y + "px";
          obj.style.bottom = x - "px";
          obj.style.right = y - "px";
          },false);         
      }
    </script>
```

ORIGINAL QUESTION AND CODE: I have a rect canvas and an image in its center. I would like to play a different audio file when a click is inside the canvas (but outside the image) and when the click is inside the image.
This is what I have for now

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid white;" onclick="myFunct()"></canvas>
<!-- audio source is specified later-->
<audio id="audio"></audio>
<script>
        var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        make_background();

        function make_background()
        {
          img = new Image();
          img.src = 'img.gif';
          img.onload = function(){
          context.drawImage(img, 100, 100);
      }
    }

    function play(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();
    }

    function myFunct() {
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
        var canv = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
           if( inside canvas and inside img){
             audio.src = "sound1.mp3";
             audio.play();
           }
           else if (inside canvas and outside img) { 
                audio.src = "sound2.mp3";
                audio.play();
           }
           else{
             audio.src = "sound3.mp3";
             audio.play();
           }
        },false);           
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start a word of caution myFunct call will bind multiple click events to your document every time you click the canvas. I have edited the fiddle to achieve something that you are looking for. Please let me know if that helps.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid white;" onclick="myFunct(event)"></canvas>
<!-- audio source is specified later-->
<audio id="audio"></audio>
<script>
    var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imageObj = make_background();
        function make_background()
        {
          img = new Image();
          img.src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100';
          img.onload = function(){
          context.drawImage(img, 100, 100);
      }
      return img;
    }

    function play(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();
    }

    function myFunct(e) {
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
        var canv = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
           if( e.clientX > 100 && e.clientX < 100 + imageObj.width && e.clientY > 100 && e.clientY < 100 + imageObj.height){
            console.log('inside image and canvas');
             //audio.src = "sound1.mp3";
             //audio.play();
           }
           else if (e.clientX > 400 || e.clientY > 400) {
            // outside canvas
                console.log('outside canvas');
                //audio.src = "sound2.mp3";
                //audio.play();
           }
           else{
            console.log('inside canvas but outside image');
             //audio.src = "sound3.mp3";
             //audio.play();
           }    
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried your code but it seems that sound 2 is played when I click in the canvas (both outside and inside image) and no sound is played when I click outside the canvas. I want multiple click events because I am changing the position of the canvas (and hence of the image) every time I click on it ( inside myFunct() I have:
         var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
         var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
         var obj = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
         obj.style.top = x + "px";
         obj.style.left = y + "px";